# Android app Feed just continuously loading

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

When opening the app or going back to my feed, it just continuously loads with no sign of ending.

I'm using HTC M8 on Android Lollipop and the latest update of SE app. Before the update, my feed worked fine.

Pulling down to refresh does not help either. Clicking on my feed icon from menu loads a partial feed, then pulling to refresh leaves me back with the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Seemingly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260466/unable-to-use-feed